# How to install grub after windows and Linux are already installed on two separate disks?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have an ubuntu 20.04 LTS install on a 1TB SSD (dev/sda). I have another 512GB SSD that has windows 10 enterprise LTSC on it. (dev/sdb) The way I currently operate is with my side panel open and I physically plug in the drive I want to use. I only ever have one of the disks connected at a time, so neither install has seen each other, but they both run on the same hardware every day. Both disks are formatted using GPT and UEFI boot. I have disabled legacy boot in the bios.

I am trying to install grub in such a way that ubuntu is the default boot and has priority over windows boot manager. I have seen windows absolutely nuke many dual-boots to no end. I have avoided this by my hand being the boot manager thus far.

I need stability.

I am seeking guidance to install grub and have both disks connected at the same time without reinstalling either operating system. I believe there has been a recent patch to grub that now allows grub installation on multiple disks for redundancy: I would like to install grub both on the 1TB SSD (dev/sda) and a flash drive I will permanently leave plugged in. (if any weirdness happens now it has a reference point to fix itself--dedicated grub drive)

I have no problem working in the terminal and using tools such as nano to edit files. I really really really don't want to mess this up as it will be a huge PITA to fix. I do have my files backed up.

To whoever answers/reads this question. I hope you are staying safe and happy and healthy throughout all this crazy. I hope one day I will be able to give back to this community that I am now asking for help.

Peace out!

Comment: I have been running dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows for years and they are on separate drives.  I have never had an issue with the Windows bootloader trying to take over mainly because when I installed Windows, I did not have my drive containing Ubuntu in the system at the time.  After Windows was installed and working, then I installed Ubuntu on the other drive and installed GRUB only to the Ubuntu drive.  I then made the Ubuntu drive the only bootable drive for my system and have never looked back.

Comment: If your Ubuntu is booting using GRUB you should only need to run sudo update-grub when both disks are plugged in, in order to add Windows to the GRUB boot menu.

Comment: sudo update-grub handled everything nicely. I went into the UEFI and disabled the windows disk on the boot list so now It can only be called by grub. My concern stems from MBR based installs which can be problematic at times. Alas everything is working. Thanks.